# How to launch LTI 1.1 complaint url using c#

Tags: c#, .net, canvas-lms

We want to launch a 3rd party web site which is a LTI tool provider and LTI 1.1 complaint. This LTI tool provider has given us url, consumer key and shared secret. Can anybody give us a sample c# code to launch this site as a window popup.

Comment: What happens if you paste url into browser address bar and run it? Will it open the website?

Comment: Providing you are using Canvas there should be a LTI section in Canvas documentation specifying how to launch basic LTI requests. There should be at least info how to configure launch with the consumer key-secret pair. LTI spec (https://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p0/implementation-guide#toc-17) calls this case: LTI link authoring

Answer (score 0):

@Niroshana - not sure if this is still relevant for you. But answering this for others who might land up here...

There is a good [open source library](https://github.com/andyfmiller/LtiLibrary) that can be used for LTI Tool Provider and LTI Tool Consumer (for .NET)